# Editing a post shows error about suggesting an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app, editor

I just tried to edit one of my questions using the app. When I hit preview and submit it gave me this error:

> [image: Error]

What is the cause and can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

As I mentioned on your other bug, I've updated the [filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) the app uses to access fetch content from the API.  The filters are backwards/forwards compatible encoded strings that look something like `)g0iMTmRaNniMgq0(nQfUJj1aHybaUZB0WC2dD2pZmozwzuw`, so naturally when editing them, I let the API do it for me.  This involves pasting the code onto the filter field like [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), making changes, then copying the new value.

Unfortunately, the app uses the yet unreleased 2.3 version of the API which provides fields like `can_edit` and `can_suggest_edit` and I accidentally re-encoded the filters that need that with a 2.2 filter editor which cropped off those values.

To test that this works, I'll be editing both this answer and your tags using the app.