# Tags are not prefixed in the <title> on the MSE question

Tags: discussion, tags, design, window-title

We had a brief conversation regarding tags at the `<title>` tag of our SE questions in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264333/editing-a-post-shows-error-about-suggesting-an-edit?noredirect=1#comment860182_264333) question.
According to our SE tagging system, most tags will automatically be prefixed into the title of the questions unless it's already in the title somewhere.

> Note that the system automatically prefixes the title with the most
>   common tag (unless it's already in the title somewhere) to help search
>   engines find it more easily.

Ref: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/245772 last line of this answer

But I didn't find any tag for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264333/editing-a-post-shows-error-about-suggesting-an-edit) question at the `<title></title>` markup of the HTML page.

*Screenshot:*

[image]

Comment: This does not apply on meta sites, and MSE is a meta site. (of Stack Exchange itself)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Ref: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/245772 last line of this
>   answer

You have taken that a bit out of context. The first sentence in that answer states:

> **Stack Overflow** has an extensive tag system...

It is discussing Stack Overflow specifically, which is a main site, and (as [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264343/no-tags-are-prefixes-in-the-title-markup-of-the-html-page-of-the-se-question#comment860193_264343) states) a tag being automatically prefixed into the title only applies on main sites, not Metas.

So the reason you did not see this occur in a title here on MSE is because it's a Meta (as per the name - *meta*.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: Also, the prefixed tag would be one of the big4, discussion, feature-request, support or bug, making a big chunk of them prefixed with "discussion -", doesn't help.