# API 2.3 Release

Tags: discussion, api, announcements

Today, we are releasing version 2.3 of the Stack Exchange API. It includes new functionality around [Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow) and Articles as well as the ability to [retract flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366976/876499). Check out the [Change Log](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log).

Comment: Is this a superset of the old undocumented api 2.3  [mentioned here](https://stackapps.com/questions/8149/please-release-and-or-document-api-version-2-3)?

Answer (score 20):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The Stack Exchange API uses snake_case for all fields so far. However, the new [`collective-report`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/collective-report) type has three fields in PascalCase: `ActivityReportDimensions`, `HealthReportDimensions`, `UsersReportDimensions`. IMHO it's not too late to change those names to conform to the unwritten rules; consistency is *everything*. You certainly don't want to let your API look like [PHP](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) ...

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The 2.3 version of the API introduced the ability to [suggest an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323798/295232) (older versions did support editing, but only if you have edit privileges). Does that still work? It is not mentioned in the change log. The mobile apps used related fields (`can_edit`, `can_suggest_edit`) on the `post` object [to determine what kind of edit action was necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264399/295232), what about those?

[This comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/7176/official-stack-overflow-ios-app#comment15435_7176) mentions tag preferences. I've never used that API but it's something to consider as well.

Finally, you might want to write an answer to my question on Stack Apps: [Please "release" and/or document API version 2.3](https://stackapps.com/q/8149/34061)

Comment: I just put a PR in for review that exposes these routes and fixes a small .net-core related bug in tag prefs.  The routes that were added are for creating suggested edits, reading and writing tag preferences, and getting network achievements.  You can already see `can_suggest_edit` in [the docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer).  These routes don't have my favorite API designs, but they work and after 7 years it's good to see them ship.

Comment: The docs are available from the main page, but you also find them under their types: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/suggested-edit, https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/achievement, and https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag-preference

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the top of the [documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) it says *Stack Exchange API v2.2* and in the first paragraph

> This is the documentation for the v2.2 Stack Exchange API

I think you want it to say 2.3 there.

Under the the heading articles it says:

> Add/Edit/Delete Only available for Business Teams via the Teams API.

That doesn't seem to be true. Works (kind of) for me on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [/articles](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/articles?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow) endpoint returns a link that isn't correct. For example [this one](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/articles/68104924?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow). It points to:

> `https://stackoverflow.com/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android`

while the actual acticle link is:

> `https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android`

Comment: They  really need to make /articles redirect in the same way as /q and /a do ([`stackoverflow.com/q/68104924`](//stackoverflow.com/q/68104924) is valid - articles are regular posts)

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess yes, that would work.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [documentation page for the `collective` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/collective) contains a [link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/collective-external-link) to the `collective-external-link` type, which 404s.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [spelling](/questions/tagged/spelling)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There appears to be a spelling mistake (one of [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366983/spelling-mistakes-in-the-api-documentation-change-log-page)) on the [Usage by collective](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-collective)  page:

[image]

I think you want that to say "identified". "An question" should be "A question".

Answer (score 8):

In order to implement retracting flags, I investigated a bit as to what's required in order to do so. In the process, I encountered several issues:

##### 1. It's impossible to know if an "in need of moderator intervention" (i.e. custom) flag has been raised and it's impossible to retract such custom flags.

Even while a custom flag is raised, the provided flag option is always `is_retraction: false` and does not contain a `has_flagged` property.

Given that a user can re-raise custom mod flags multiple times, the `has_flagged` property is probably better used to effectively mean "there is a custom flag currently active", or, effectively, "can_not_raise_new_flag_right_now".

##### 2. It is impossible to tell which flag is currently active

Once a user has raised a flag, the responses for each of types they have raised, regardless of if the flag has been retracted or handled, always have `has_flagged: true`, `is_retraction: true`, and an `option_id`. Once the flag has been retracted or handled, there should be some indication that it's no longer possible to retract. Probably the best thing would be to just not have `is_retraction: true` and no `option_id`.

In other words, what's received from the API is identical in the following states:

1. Can retract: flag currently raised and active (not yet handled)
2. Can't retract: flag previously raised, but not active (already handled), or flag previously raised, but not active (user has retracted)

Without being able to differentiate between these, to retract a flag, one has to walk through trying to retract *every* possible entry. This could include 30+ options (if close-votes/flags are changed to work for retracting). That is, potentially, a substantial number of requests in order to retract a single flag. Ideally, if the user can't retract or raise a flag, then there should not be either an `is_retraction: true` or an `option_id` property.

NOTE: Custom moderator flags can be raised again, even if previously handled or retracted. So, it should not be assumed that just because a user has already retracted they can't re-raise a flag. That they can't re-raise a flag is the case for other types of flags, but not, at least, close-flags which can age away and be re-raised. I'm not sure if other aged-away flags can be re-raised.

##### 3. If a spam or R/A flag has been raised, then both flag types show `has_flagged: true` and `is_retraction: true`, but only one works to retract.

You can't raise or retract the one of these flag types which the user hasn't already raised. The one which hasn't been raised should either have a new property like `can_flag: false`, just not be returned as an option, or be returned with no `has_flagged`, no `is_retraction`, and no `option_id` (i.e. indicate that the user hasn't actually raised it, but that they can't raise or retract it).

NOTE: Don't make the assumption that users can *never* raise both a spam and R/A flag, because moderators *can* do that, just not at the same time (and it's a useful capability in some cases).

##### 4. Can't retract close-votes or close-flags (also reported by [Xnero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/707129/xnero) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367523/271271))

- When a close-vote or close-flag is raised, the top level options for closing indicate `is_retraction: true`, but don't contain an `option_id`. None of the `sub_options` have `is_retraction: true`, but each contains an `option_id`, which doesn't work for retracting.
- Once a close-flag or close-vote is raised, `/questions/{id}/close/options` returns no data.
- There should be a *single* `option_id` which is for retracting the close-flag/vote. It's detrimental to have to select whichever of the `sub_options` was selected by the user when raising the flag in order to retract it (i.e. you should be able to retract by using an `option_id` provided on the top level of the flag options description list).
- Currently, when a close-vote/flag is active, `/questions/{id}/flags/options` returns >25 separate `option_id` values which ostensibly permit raising an additional close-vote/flag (but don't work to do anything other than get an error).

#### There should only ever be a single flag option with `is_retraction: true` and an `option_id` returned by the API.

If a flag is *currently* raised and there's only one `option_id` which will actually function to retract the currently raised flag, then there should be only a single flag option Object returned which has both `is_retraction: true` and an `option_id`. If there are options provided where both of those are present, but which won't actually work, then the API is returning data that's really invalid. In fact, the API should only ever be returning `option_id` values which the user *could* actually use, so under the conditions of having a currently active flag, and assuming we can't raise more than one flag at a time, then there should be only a single `option_id` provided in the entire data returned by the API, as there's only one such `option_id` that is *actually valid* at the time the request is made of the API to provide the current valid flagging options for the user.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [retracted-flags](/questions/tagged/retracted-flags)

### Please don't make flag retraction use the exact same query as casting flags

Currently, if someone uses a query to cast a flag, `/flags/add`, and the same user has already cast the exact same type of flag, it will cause the flag to be retracted. As per [this staff post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367517/377214), this behavior is intentional for this new version of the API.

However, this behavior isn't ideal. For starters, it's not semantically correct to *remove* a flag on receiving a command to *cast* a flag. It can result in problems where if someone submits the same query twice, either by accident or in order to ensure that their first attempt went through if they're not sure of that, the flag will be unexpectedly removed. Second, it makes current API 2.2 scripts much more difficult to port to the new API, especially scripts that [depend on errors being received upon trying to recast an already-cast flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367431/377214). Those scripts will have to use more API quota for this purpose, as they'll have to make a second call to ascertain if a flag was already cast.

Can this design feature please be removed (i.e. reverted to how it used to work in 2.2, with errors being returned instead of flags being retracted), and it replaced with another, explicit way to retract flags, such as a query parameter `?is_retraction=1` or a separate endpoint such as `/flags/retract`?

Comment: Notes: A) It doesn't increase the quota use. The same number of API accesses were required under both 2.2 and 2.3. B) Submitting the same *exact* query twice won't result in retracting the flag. There should be an error generated in that case (not tested by me). C) The issue is that code written for 2.2 doesn't look for the new `is_retraction: true` parameter, and other than that the data it GETs from `../flags/options` looks identical to what it would have gotten from 2.2. If the code hasn't been updated to look for that, it will think a `option_id` indicating retraction is one for raising.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[retracted-flags](/questions/tagged/retracted-flags)

### Recommended closure flags cannot be retracted

If a question is flagged as any "needs improvement" option or as a "duplicate", `is_retraction` is set to `true` for both `"a duplicate"` and `"needs improvement"` but no `option_id` is provided for either option making it impossible to retract the flag from the API.

Expected API output for any other type of flag:

> [image]

Output for any "needs improvement" or "duplicate option" (notice the absence of `option_id`):

> [image]