# Spelling mistakes in the API documentation change log page

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, spelling

There are some spelling mistakes in the API documentation [Change Log](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log) page, under the **Version 2.0** section.

| Section name | Spelling mistake | Supposed to be |
| --- | --- | --- |
| General Changes | reponse | re**s**ponse |
| Method Changes | Assocation | Assoc**i**ation |
| General Additions | addtion | add**i**tion |

[image: General Changes]
[image: Method Changes]
[image: General Additions]

Comment: [Lots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366984/798831) of mistakes here.  Sticky keys, I guess.

Comment: Not sure if guids is a mistake. I'm guessing it's supposed to be [Globally Unique IDentifier (GUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), though it would be better if it was capitalized (i.e. GUIDs)

Comment: Yeah... "*`/users/{id}/associated` now expects account ids to be passed, not association guids.*" should definitely be "GUIDs", not "guides". The latter doesn't make sense in this context. I definitely think capitalization would make it clearer, but I'm unsure whether I'd call that a "typo".

Comment: *[GUID](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/GUID#Noun)* (plural *GUIDs*) is the primary spelling.