# Stack Apps sidebar needs to be updated to reflect the API version changes

Tags: bug, api, sidebar, stackapps

On [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/), in the sidebar, it says:

[image]

Shouldn't that say "API 2.3"?

Comment: A note on why I posted here instead of SA:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366977/api-2-3-release#comment1222836_366980, SA also has no Meta and the question might get buried.

Comment: We do have a meta. https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/meta and we don't have that much traffic that  posts get buried ...

Comment: @rene I stand corrected.